# What's the maximum length of a method name in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I'm using RubyMine which informs me that

```
unsubscribe_from_all_notifications
```

...is too long for a method name. What's the max length?

Comment: try reducing the length of this method name gradually and see at what point it accepts it. ;)

Comment: I'm guessing it's a RubyMine issue; I tried a method with name `unsubscribe_from_all_notifications_and_keep_making_this_bloody_thing_longer_and_longer_and_longer_and_longer_and_longer` and it works just fine in Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2...

Comment: lol...thanks! The program was working, but I couldn't help wondering if I was screwing something up.

Comment: It is a warning, not an error ;) If it is annoying for you follow oldfartdevelopers answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

RubyMine lies :-) Or at least does not mean that it is a limitation of Ruby interpreter.

```
looong_name = "a" * 10000; # => "aaaaaaaaa.....
a_class = Class.new
a_class.__send__(:define_method, looong_name) { :hello }
a_class.new.__send__(looong_name) # => :hello

puts a_class.instance_methods.inspect # you better not run this :-)
```

Comment: Regarding "you better not run this": Why not? (Because the output will be some 10,000+ characters?)

Comment: @JonSchneider indeed, your entire console will be filled with "aaaaaaaaaaa..." :-)

Answer (score 22):

In **RubyMine**, you can change the maximum length for all categories of Ruby names by:

1. Select menu item **RubyMine** --> **Preferences**
2. In the resulting modal dialog in the left pane under **Editor**, select **Inspections**.
3. In the resulting pane in the right, select **Ruby** --> **Naming Conventions**.
4. You have nine categories of Ruby names to change.  Each one shows an edit field for **Max Length**.  So, for example, I changed them all from 20 or 30 to 60.  Click **Apply** for each of the nine categories you change.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no limit to the size of a method name in ruby.

Most likely you have some coding style setup in RubyMine which is showing you this warning. If on a mac check RubyMine > Preferences > Code Style > Ruby and see if there is some sort of preference in there.

Just to let you know I use RubyMine as well but I do not see this type of coding style set for me.